# cache insert object without specifying any dependencies,expiry etc item disappear miraculously

Tags: c#, .net

We use the Cache object as a flag to identify if a certain username is already logged in. 
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(SessionObjects.CurrentUserId.ToString(), Session.SessionID);

There is a action filter which basically checks if this item exists in the cache. If it does then the user is logged out

However sometimes I'm finding this object miraculously disappears and causes null exceptions when trying to retrieve it from the cache within the action filter.

I notice we don't seem to specify any expiration/ dependency specifics. Given the sample code above, are there any conditions where .net could of removed this entry for me without my permission?

Comment: Are you sure the appdomain didn't recycle in the mean time?

Comment: Does app domain recycle whilest running out of visual studio

Comment: Can't rule that out.

Comment: Ok so how can i prevent this temporarily to see if this os the problem

Comment: You are using a `Cache` incorrectly. This way of attacking the problem (i.e. assuming your memory is a permanent data store) will buy you lots of pain. For example - every time IIS recycles you will 'lose' the data. If memory usage is excessive you will 'lose' the data. If the machine reboots you will 'lose' the data. If you use a web garden or web farm you will 'lose' the data. You need to shift the data to a more permanent caching layer (e.g. Redis).

Comment: mjwills so what is the cache meant to be used for then? Or are you saying I shouldn't be using the Cache object as a reliable pernament store since what stored in it can be subjected to garbabge collection?

Comment: `mjwills so what is the cache meant to be used for then?` For temporary in-memory storage. `Or are you saying I shouldn't be using the Cache object as a reliable pernament store since what stored in it can be subjected to garbabge collection?` No I am not saying that. Read my comment again. All of those scenarios will result in the cache being lost. None of them are related to garbage collection (well 'memory usage is excessive' is _kind of_ related to GC).